# How to extract IP address from Amazon hostname?

Tags: linux, networking, bash, amazon-ec2

I really don't know why, but Amazon Web Services provided me with some weird hostnames for my machines. Now I need to list all them with knife to use in a bash script. I'm saying that the IPs are weird because none place you can resolve the hostname, which is useless though after all.

In my script, I would like to extract only the IP from the hostname. For example, extract 10.114.152.134 from the following hostname:

```
ip-10-114-152-134.valter.henrique.com
```

How can I do that?

Comment: To clarify, `ip-10-114-152-134.valter.henrique.com` is the "weird hostname" Amazon gives you, and you want to extract the IP address from it?

Comment: Couldn't you just ping the hostname?

Comment: @slhck If you're talking about getting the IP from a hostname via a DNS lookup, that's more for `nslookup` (or `dig` or `host`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This snippet surely can be improved, but it should do the job:

```
hostname=ip-10-114-152-134.valter.henrique.com
hostip=$(echo ${hostname%%.*} | sed -e 's/ip-//' -e 's/-/./g')
```

`${hostname%%.*}` removes everything after (and including) the first `.`; `sed` then removes the starting `ip-` and replaces then the dashes with dots.

---

You can also use only one `sed` command:

```
echo ip-10-114-152-134.valter.henrique.com | sed 's/ip-\(.*\)-\(.*\)-\(.*\)-\(.*\)\.valter\.henrique\.com/\1.\2.\3.\4/'
```

The regex in the first brackets (you need to escape these:  `\(.*\)` ) gets assigned to `\1` and so on.

---

Here is the last variant, using only bash functions:

```
IFSsave="$IFS"; IFS=-                            # save IFS prior modifying it
hostip=""
hostname=ip-10-114-152-134.valter.henrique.com   # initial values
hostname=${hostname#*-}                          # remove the "ip-" part
hostname=${hostname%%.*}                         # remove the ".valter.henrique.com" part
for i in $hostname; do                           # loop over 10-114-152-134, splitted at "-" ($IFS)
   hostip="${hostip}${i}."                       # append number. to $hostip
done
hostip=${hostip%.}                               # remove trailing dot
echo $hostip                                     # print resulting IP
IFS="$IFSsave"                                   # restore IFS
```

Answer (score 4):

This is less robust than mpy's Bash-only variation since it assumes that the IP address portion always falls in the same position, but it's a little shorter and a little faster.

```
hostname=ip-10-114-152-134.valter.henrique.com
IFSsave=$IFS
IFS=.-
parts=($hostname)
hostip="${parts[*]:1:4}"
IFS=$IFSsave
echo "$hostip"
```

Using `*` as an array subscript inside quotes causes the first character of `IFS` to be inserted between each element of the array. Setting `IFS` to two characters causes the split to be done at either of them.

By the way, that domain name resolves like this for me:

```
$ host ip-10-114-152-134.valter.henrique.com
ip-10-114-152-134.valter.henrique.com has address 208.91.197.27
```

The address 10.114.152.134 is a private IP which is not routable over the internet. It's probably only reachable within the AWS network.

Comment: That's elegant - especially that `parts[*]` trick. But what is the `parts=($d)` doing, I mean, what is `$d` or should it read `$hostname`?

Comment: @mpy: It's a typo. I'll fix it. Thanks. I also realized that `IFS` only needs to be set once.